# 0% Classes code coverage in phpunit/xdebug

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I'm using PHPUnit/Xdebug for running unit tests and although my Methods and Lines coverage percentile is in the 90s, Classes always reads as 0%. How is the classes coverage determined and is there something special I need to define to trigger it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you test the class and create it?  My classes get proper code coverage.

Comment: I have test classes which instantiate the class I'm testing, if that's what you mean. Here's a [sample test class](https://github.com/seagoj/devtools/blob/master/tests/MarkdownTest.php), if you care to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through trial and error, I've determined that the classes tick off once the Methods and Lines for that class are at 100% coverage.

Comment: Correct, the entire class is not "covered" until all of its parts are covered.